# user specific persistent cck types in drupal

Tags: drupal

Is there a way to do the following. We need to have a few basic cck types that will allow users to track their chosen parameters over a length of time.

For example, one cck type may be called "numeric tracker" It would have a field for labeling the type and a field for entering a number.

User A might label one numeric tracker "miles driven". Then each day user A would use this type to enter a number. User B might label a numeric tracker "hours slept". Each day user B would enter a number.

Is there a way to use cck in this way?

Comment: Why not have an extra CCK text field where the user enters the description and display that to the user next to their numeric value, and hide the numeric value's actual label in the theme code?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, cck can handle this, but if I'm getting your requirements correctly I believe you may just be looking at the problem in the wrong way.

For tracking data like this I would create a content type:

```
Tracking Data
  Has CCK Numeric Slider
  Has CCK User
```

Then each day the user would create a new node of this type that would be associated with the user that created this.  So instead of having one node that many user contribute to you have many nodes each associated with a user.  You can then use views to group your nodes back together and display you data in a way that emulates your requirements.  IE the end user never really know that under the presentation layer there are many nodes.

Additionally you can use *rules* to ensure that the user can only create one every 24 hours.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. This will be a big help. 

I do not fully understand however, When you say, "has CCK Numeric Slider", how do I incorporate the cck type "Numeric Slider" into the cck type "Tracking Data". 

Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Maybe openist is talking about [Textfiled to slider module](http://drupal.org/project/slider_textfield)

Comment: Sorry yes, I was just using a test slider as an example, but yes the texified to slider module dusan posted looks like it would work great.

Comment: Thanks again. Is there a way to have the "user" field autopopulate with the user's name?

Comment: Also, I think I still see a problem. Ideally we would be able to provide the users with a page that would have all of the trackers they  create in one place. So, if a user created a "miles driven" tracker, this would show up on this page. 

Is there a way to do this using this method?

Comment: 1) The author field with be auto-populated with the user that created it, so you should not have to worry about that
2) If I'm understanding what your saying, it's possible, you'll just have to dig around in the views interface for a while to get exactly what you require.  http://drupal.org/project/views